# How do I open .emz files on linux?

Tags: files, images

I want to view or open `.emz` file on Linux.

EMZ file extension is a Windows Compressed Enhanced Metafile file.

How I have to open this file.
Any software required?

I don't want to convert through online sites.

Answer (score 8):

`.emz` files are apparently `.emf` files which have been compressed in a way that can be decompressed with `gzip`.

For example:

```
# uncompresses 'in-place' but loses the filename suffix entirely
gunzip -S .emz filename.emz
```

or

```
# creates new uncompressed file with .emf extension.
zcat filename.emz > filename.emf
```

Once you've decompressed the file, you should be able to convert it to pdf or tiff as described in this answer on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976438/i-have-a-few-emf-files-how-i-can-convert-them-into-ps-pdf-tiff-on-linux

The following blog post indicates that `.emf` files can be opened with the OpenOffice or LibreOffice Draw or Writer applications: http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.com/2011/11/libreoffice-unlikely-image-viewer.html

I'd guess that LibreOffice/OpenOffice could probably open the `.emz` files without decompressing them first.  Try it and see.

You mention that you can't even open this `.emz` file in windows itself.  That probably indicates that the file is corrupted or invalid.

Comment: I can confirm that I can open `*.emz` files with `LibreOffice Draw v7.5.1.2`.

Comment: I used the gunzip -S command, added the emf file extension, and LibreOffice Draw was able to display the file